# Run flutter application in kiosk mode

Tags: 20.04, raspberrypi, kiosk, flutter

I want to know if it's possible to run a Flutter app in a Raspberry Pi, running Ubuntu.
The thing is, I need this raspberry to run only the app in fullscreen mode. I found about kiosk mode, but nothing about "Flutter app in Kiosk mode".

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What difference would the app being in Flutter make? Gtk, Qt, Flutter, tkinter, it's all the same as far as that is concerned. What have you tried so far, and what happened when you tried it?